# SendMessageAsync unauthorized access exception

Tags: c#, windows, sms

I am building app for windows phone 10. At some point app should send sms. This is the code I used:

```
public async Task SendMessage(string phoneNumber, string text)
        {
            ChatMessage msg = new ChatMessage();
            msg.MessageKind = Windows.ApplicationModel.Chat.ChatMessageKind.Standard;
            msg.Body = text;
            msg.Recipients.Add(phoneNumber);
            ChatMessageStore cms = await ChatMessageManager.RequestStoreAsync();

            if (cms.ValidateMessage(msg).Status == ChatMessageValidationStatus.Valid)
                await cms.SendMessageAsync(msg);
        }
```

I get unauthorized access exception in last line:

```
        await cms.SendMessageAsync(msg);
```

I call the function like this:

```
        await messagesForSending.SendMessage("+38162275031", "proba");
```

In app manifest I checked Chat Message Access.
Does anyone have a solution for this problem? Thanks.